# How to write a a reverse function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, reverse

So, I know, there is a built in function to reverse a list in Haskell, but I'm trying to write my own little function, just to practice some Haskell. I thought of the following code, which sadly is not working. Could you guys tell me what I did wrong?

```
    rev :: [Int] -> [Int]
    rev [] = []
    rev [x] = last [x] : rev init [x]
```

Comment: `[x]` is a list containing a single element (named `x`). `last [x]` is just `x` and `init [x]` is `[]`. So `last [x] : rev init [x]` is `x : rev []`, which is `x : []`, which is `[x]`. So your last line is equivalent to `rev [x] = [x]`. But your main problem is that you don't have a case for lists that have more than one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
rev :: [Int] -> [Int]
rev [] = []
rev x = last x : rev (init x)
```

Explanation: [x] was a list containing x, whereas you want to operate directly with x

ps. here's the [documentation for Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html). And remember to `import Data.List`

Comment: This is what i was searching for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Please remember to accept the answer (click the green tick) if you feel it answered your question well.

Comment: I don't think this even parses with `let` in it :S

Comment: Thank you for spotting the error. `let` is removed.

Comment: I think this is not an efficient `reverse` function due to many calls of the expensive `last` function. I think [Valy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43937822/4543207) shows a better way of doing this job.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it efficiently, I'd recommend you use an accumulator:

```
rev :: [a] -> [a]
rev xs = go xs []
   where
   go :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
   go []     ys = ys
   go (x:xs) ys = go xs (x:ys)
```

The function `go`, at each step, removes one element from the first list `xs` and prepends it to the second list `ys`. This is similar to popping from a stack and pushing to another stack -- which reverses the order.

Since we only use a constant amount of time at each recursive call, we get O(n) complexity, where n is the list length.

Instead, if at each recursive call we use `last` or append with `... ++ [x]`, we pay O(n) for each call, hence O(n^2) overall.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
rev :: [Int] -> [Int]
rev [] = []
rev (x:l) = (rev l) ++ [x]
```

The 3rd line takes the first element from the list and then creates a list containing only that element. This is appended to the result of the recursion `rev l` call.